# Problem with formatting two hidden grey boxes, one after the other

Tags: support, markdown, spoilers

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/878483/39599), I used two hidden grey boxes, one after the other. However, I had some trouble getting them to format probably.

If you write

```
>! Line 1

>! Line 2
```

you get

> ! Line 1
>
> ! Line 2

In order to fix this, it seems that you have to place some text between the two lines. For example,

```
>! Line 1

$ $

>! Line 2
```

produces

> Line 1

$ $

> Line 2

as desired.

Is this necessary? If so, can it be fixed?

Comment: Maybe related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9454/multiline-hidden-text, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/big-tex-wont-get-hidden-by, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/how-to-put-math-equations-in-a-spoiler-block

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known inconvenience: [Consecutive spoiler blocks (>!) are shown as blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144824/), which is due to the [design of spoiler syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72878/). It can be solved by inserting HTML comment `<!-->` or empty heading `#` to separate the blocks. This is better than MathJax-based hacks, as no JavaScript needs to run to render it.

> Line 1

> Line 2

was made with

```
>! Line 1

<!-->       
>! Line 2
```

Also,

> Line 1

> Line 2

was made with

```
>! Line 1

#       
>! Line 2
```